# Merge commits from multiple users

Tags: git, github

Our organization has decided to use Github to make simultaneous code modification possible. One of the features we are looking for is to be able to merge all the changes made on one file by multiple developers and replace the existing (or create a new) file. We are not really sure if this is possible.

I used Github before but I had never tried collaborating with other people. I just mainly use it to control my development progress.

Main question:
[2 commits from different users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyEL7.jpg)

Is it possible to merge 2 commits (or more) from multiple users if the changes they are proposing only affects the same file?

**NOTE:**

- Working A: Removed and edited some lines
- Working B: Added some new lines

Comment: Working in the same file may give merge conflicts. Don't worry though! They can normally be easily resolved.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I’ve tested it and I think the onlt way to resolve the conflict is by removing the added lines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) or [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) (depends how you want history of project to look like). If all users have write access to the same repo, you may want to allow them to [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) from/to specific branch instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I’ve considered merge at first but I’m not sure that is the solution I’m looking for. If Developer A removed some lines and merged it into the original file then Developer B’s file would still have the removed lines and will be re-added back if he merged it. Not sure if I explained it clearly.

Comment: Merging is definitely the way to go here. `git` knows the common merge source of the changed file and acts accordingly, trying to merge properly and if that fails reporting a merge conflict that you have to solve manually. Your use case is one of the exact problems `git` adresses: being able to combine changes different developers made on the same file.